# increase number of columns in window using jupyter qtconsole in python

Tags: python, jupyter, qtconsole, jupyter-console

I have a QtConsole running. Whenever I output a matrix (for example) that has many columns, QtConsole wraps the matrix to the next line. However, the break point is only halfway through my window.. lots of wasted blank space. How can I make QtConsole use more columns in it's output?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy then take a loot at `np.set_printoptions`.  Try adjusting the  linewidth argument; the default is 75.  So maybe run `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=150)` and see if that helps.